# Obtaining values from a 3D matrix based locations in a 2D matrix

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, array-broadcasting

Assuming I had a numpy matrix: `data = np.random.rand(200, 50, 100)` and had the locations I needed the values from: `locs = np.random.randint(50, size=(200, 2))`.

How would I obtain a resulting matrix of shape `(200, 2, 100)`? Essentially, I would like to obtain the values from `data` at the locations specified by `locs`.

If I do: `data[locs]`, I end up with a resulting matrix of shape `(200, 2, 50, 100)` and not  `(200, 2, 100)`.

Updated with more details as requested:

If we have:

```
data = np.arange(125)
reshaped = np.reshape(data, (5, 5, 5))
locs = [[3, 4], [2, 1], [1, 3], [3, 3], [0, 0]]
```

Then doing something like `data[locs]` should give the following output:

```
array([[[ 15,  16,  17,  18,  19],
        [ 20,  21,  22,  23,  24]],

       [[ 35,  36,  37,  38,  39],
        [ 30,  31,  32,  33,  34]],

       [[ 55,  56,  57,  58,  59],
        [ 65,  66,  67,  68,  69]],

       [[ 90,  91,  92,  93,  94],
        [ 90,  91,  92,  93,  94]],

       [[100, 101, 102, 103, 104],
        [100, 101, 102, 103, 104]]])
```

Comment: Show a smaller example of what you mean "at the locations". You have a `(200, 50, 100)` input and a `(200, 2)` index. How do you actually intend to map that to the output? Writing a `for` loop can be a helpful tool as well.

Comment: What I'm saying is that the shape of the output tells you nothing by itself. The content is quite important.

Comment: I've answered what I think is you are asking, but please clarify the question. There are a number of ways of getting the `200` dimension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of an advanced index is going to be the shape of the indices along the dimensions that you are indexing. `data[locs]` is equivalent to `data[locs, :, :]`, so your shape will be `locs.shape + data.shape[1:]`, or `(200, 2, 50, 100)`.

What you *appear* to be asking for is to index axis 1 of `data` using `locs`, keeping axis 0 in lockstep with the row in `locs`. To do this, you need to index with `locs` along axis 1, and supply an index that goes from 0 to 200 in axis zero.

It is important to remember that all the advanced indices must broadcast to the same shape. Since `locs` is shaped `(200, 2)`, the first index must be shaped `(200, 1)` or `(200, 2)` to broadcast properly. I will show the former, since it is simpler and more efficient.

```
data = np.random.rand(200, 50, 100)
locs = np.random.randint(50, size=(200, 2))
rows = np.arange(200).reshape(-1, 1)

result = data[rows, locs, :]
```

Comment: I did want axis 1 to be in lockstep with axis 0. 
Doing this works! Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad it worked out. And thanks for updating the question.